# Hover image - part of forms appears untill hover another How?

Tags: jquery, css, forms, hover

Im trying to make part of my form/questionnaire appears when hover on image and stay active untill hover another image next to it. and repeat it on 7 images.
Of course I need the cheched checkboxes to stay after they'll be hidden so you can come back to them by hover the image and for ex. correct answers and so on..

I was using a j code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$("#Oobj51").hover(function(){
$('#Oobj58').show();
},function(){
$('#Oobj58').hide();
});
</script>
```

it works to another elements on my page but not to the form.

how can i do it maybe with css class or another j code. Thanks!

Parts of html: (let's say I want to hover on "Oobj56" and make "Oobj58" appears and stay as I said before...)

```
<div id="Oobj56">
<button type="submit" class="przed6" onmouseover="this.className='po6'" 

onmouseout="this.className='przed6'" />
</div>

<div id="Oobj57">
<button type="submit" class="przed7" onmouseover="this.className='po7'" 

onmouseout="this.className='przed7'" />
</div>

<div id="Oobj60">
<form action="mailto:" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

<div id="Oobj59">

<input type="text" input size="8" name="imie" placeholder="imię">

<input type="text" input size="11" name="numer" placeholder="numer telefonu">
<br><br>

<select name="miasto">
<option selected="Miasto">Miasto</option>
<option>Wrocław</option>
    <option>Warszawa</option>
<option>Kraków</option>
<option>Trójmiasto</option>
<option>Poznań</option>
    <option>Szczecin</option>
<option>Toruń</option>
<option>Łódź</option>
    <option>Bydgoszcz</option>
<option>Lublin</option>
<option>Katowice</option>
</select>

<select name="wiek">
<option selected="selected">Wiek</option>
<option> <15 </option>
<option>15-19</option>
<option>20-24</option>
<option>25-29</option>
    <option>30-34</option>
<option>35-39</option>
<option>40-44</option>
    <option>45-49</option>
<option>50-54</option>
<option>55-59</option>
    <option>60-64</option>
<option>65-69</option>
<option>70-74</option>
    <option> >75 </option>
</select>

<select name="plec">
<option selected="selected">Płeć</option>
<option>Mężczyzna</option>
<option>Kobieta</option>
</select></div>


<div id="Oobj58">

<script language="JavaScript">
function toggle(source) {
checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('sport');
for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="gym" />siłownia<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="fitness" />fitness<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="noga" />piłka nożna<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="kosz" />koszykówka<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="siata" />siatkówka<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="ameryka" />football amerykański<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="konie" />jeździectwo konne<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="basen" />basen/sporty wodne<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="sport" value="zima" />sporty zimowe<br />

</div>




<div id="Oobj15">

<input type="submit" style="font-family: Open Sans;" value="Wyślij" class="wyslij" />
</div></form>


</div>
```

class to "Oobj57" is

```
.przed7{
background: url('image/praca.png') no-repeat;
width: 84px;
height: 84px;
border-style: none;
}

.po7{
background: url('image/praca_wybr.png') no-repeat;
width: 84px;
height: 84px;
border-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you actually have div `#Oobj51` in your `html`? Working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/TX5fw/1/

Comment: Yes I have. I can see it works here .. still don't have any idea why not on my page. 
maybe the problem is where i put js code. where in my html should i write it ?

Comment: Ok. JS worked. 
I must've paste it in wrong place at the beggining. 

Now i paste it inside Oobj51 div. 
Thanks

Comment: You need to wrap your `jQuery` code into `$(document).ready()` and it should work. Take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TX5fw/2/)

Comment: But now there is still one problem. 
of course obvious but don't know how to overcome it.

When img not hover - there is no possibility to check boxes ;D and where not hover there is no checkboxes

Comment: Do on hover show, on click hide. Don't know what you are after with your code. Leave all your `javascript` in head section of `html` or straight after the `</body>` tag

Comment: Works but i don't want it to hide on clik :P i want it to hide when hover another element

Comment: Have: 

    <div id="Oobj51">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
    $('#Oobj51').hover(function() {
    $("#Oobj58").show(500);
    }), $("#Oobj58").hover(function() {
    //do nothing if hovered over
    }, function(){
    //hide on hover out
    $("#Oobj58").hide(500);
    });
    });
    </script>
    <button type="submit" class="przed"  onmouseover="this.className='po'"                            onmouseout="this.className='przed'"/>
    </div>

How to make the Oobj58 disaapear not when hover out but when hover  next img "Oobj52" where next form part should appear.?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood your question.

I suppose you can use the onmouseover event attribute in the image tag.

Comment: Add a comment asking for more details instead of answer, if you don't understand the question.

Comment: Ok, easier - i want the effect like: when mouse on "Oobj57" - "Oobj58" (which is part of my form) appears and stays untill mouse on "Oobj56" when another part of form should appear and stay... so on. I added class to my img "Oobj57" above.  
so it already works with onmouseover and now i want to add another element but don't know how

Comment: First create all the forms and set their 'display' css property to 'none'. When it is supposed to appear, simply set their 'display' property to 'block'.

Comment: I can set display to none. No probl. 
but don't know how to write this "when it is supposed to apper" in css

Comment: On the image tag, set the 'onmouseover' event attribute to point to a function that resets the 'display' property of the form to 'block'. It should look something like f.style.display="block";

Comment: Im to stupid to write it on my own ;) I've started to reading about html and css yesterday. 
prefer to stay with this js code, that should work. especially that my img tag already has one onmouseover attribute that change itself when hover. 
question is where in this html should i paste js code to make it work.. cause as I can see it works on the link above in comment

Comment: Ok. JS worked. 
I must've paste it in wrong place at the beggining. 

Now i paste it inside Oobj51 div.